# Vue - Toggle class through multiple buttons

Tags: toggle, vue.js

I have a Vue component, which displays a Vote button. When the user clicks on the Vote button an .active class gets added. Now I need to make sure only one Vote button can have this .active class at any given time.

What do I need to change in my code:

```
Vue.component('moustache', {
    name: 'moustache',
    props: ['type', 'img'],
    template: `<li>
                 <p><strong>@{{ type }}</strong></p>
                 <img width="300" height="200" :src="img">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }" :data-type="type" @click="toggleClass">
                   Vote
                 </button>
              </li>`,
    data: function(){
        return{
            isActive: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleClass(){
                this.isActive = !this.isActive;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each moustache component should only be in control of its own state. In the situation you describe, it would be best to let a parent component handle updating all the buttons when one is clicked.

In general:

1. Button is clicked in moustache component
2. Moustache component emits a "activated" event
3. The parent component listens for the "activated" event, and updates the state of all the buttons

Here is an example in code:

```js
Vue.component('moustache', {
  name: 'moustache',
  props: ['type', 'img', 'isActive'],
  template: `<li>
                 <p><strong>@{{ type }}</strong></p>
                 <img width="300" height="20" :src="img">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }" :data-type="type" @click="toggleClass">
                   Vote
                 </button>
              </li>`,
  methods: {
    toggleClass() {
      this.$emit('activate')
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttons: [{
      isActive: false,
      type: 'Button 1',
      img: null
    }, {
      isActive: false,
      type: 'Button 2',
      img: null
    }, {
      isActive: false,
      type: 'Button 3',
      img: null
    }, ]
  },
  methods: {
    activateButton: function(activatedButton) {
      for (let button of this.buttons) {
        button.isActive = button === activatedButton
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <moustache v-for="button in buttons" 
             :is-active="button.isActive"
             :type="button.type"
             :src="button.src"
             v-on:activate="activateButton(button)"></moustache>
</div>
```

Of course, this approach only works if all of Vote buttons can be controlled by the same parent component. If you require more complex behaviour, then it might be worth looking into [Vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html). Then the state of your buttons could be managed by a vuex store.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I'm just hesitant to use this method because I don't like the idea of listing all the buttons in the data. For instance how would this work when I plugged it into a database and used v-for for the components?

Comment: You can populate the `buttons` array from a database. The example I provided uses v-for for the components.